# Extracting particular string from a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have a copy of HTML code in a TEXT file,So i need to EXTRACT few information from that code,I managed to do it like this ,but i'm not getting any specific patterns to EXTRAXT the text.

```
Position : 27
        <a href="https://www.fliegende-pillen.de/product/doppelherz-folsaeure-800-b-vitamine-tabletten.230477.html?p=466453&amp;noCS=1&amp;adword=google/PLA&amp;pk_campaign=google/PLA" id="vplap26" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" class="plantl pla-unit-single-clickable-target clickable-card" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" aria-label="0,12 € / 1,00 St. Doppelherz Folsäure 800+B-Vitamine Tabletten 40 St. for €4.64 from fliegende-pillen.de" data-nt-icon-id="planti26" data-title-id="vplaurlt26" jsaction="mouseover:pla.sntiut;mouseout:pla.hntiut"></a>

Position : 28
        <a href="https://www.vitaminexpress.org/de/ultra-b-complex-vitamin-b-kapseln" id="vplap27" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" class="plantl pla-unit-single-clickable-target clickable-card" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" aria-label="Ultra B Complex for €21.90 from vitaminexpress.org" data-nt-icon-id="planti27" data-title-id="vplaurlt27" jsaction="mouseover:pla.sntiut;mouseout:pla.hntiut"></a>

Position : 29
        <a href="https://www.narayana-verlag.de/Vitalstoff-Komplex-von-Robert-Franz-90-Kapseln/b22970" id="vplap28" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" class="plantl pla-unit-single-clickable-target clickable-card" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" aria-label="Vitalstoff-Komplex - von Robert Franz - 90 Kapseln for €26.00 from Narayana Verlag" data-nt-icon-id="planti28" data-title-id="vplaurlt28" jsaction="mouseover:pla.sntiut;mouseout:pla.hntiut"></a>
```

I want to EXTRACT the URL link after "href",and the name of the Product after the TEXT "aria-label".How can i do that in Python?

Currently i'm using the below script for finding the lines which is of interest to me,

```
import psycopg2

try:

    filepath = filePath='''/Users/lins/Downloads/pladiv.txt''' 

    with open(filePath, 'r') as file:

       print('entered loop')
       cnt=1
       for line in file: 
        if 'pla-unit-single-clickable-target clickable-card" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" aria-label="' in line:
          print('Position : ' + str(cnt))
          cnt=cnt+1
          if 'href="' in line:
            print(line)
            fields=line.split(";")
            #print(fields[0] + '  as URL')

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        quit()
```

Note: I was inserting it to my PostgreSQL DB, The code is removed in the above sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use regex, like this

```
import re

url = '<p>Hello World</p><a href="http://example.com">More Examples</a><a href="http://example2.com">Even More Examples</a>'

urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', url)

>>> print urls
['http://example.com', 'http://example2.com']
```

Or you can parse the file as HTML

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
>>> html = Soup(s, 'html.parser')           # Soup(s, 'lxml') if lxml is installed
>>> [a['href'] for a in html.find_all('a')]
['http://example.com', 'http://example2.com']
```

Either way both is fine. 
EDIT - to get the entire value of href you can use this,

```
url = """<a href="http://www.fliegende-pillen.de/product/doppelherz-folsaeure-800-b-vitamine-tabletten.230477.html?p=466453&amp;noCS=1&amp;adword=google/PLA&amp;pk_campaign=google/PLA" id="vplap26" onmousedown="return google.arwt(this)" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" class="plantl pla-unit-single-clickable-target clickable-card" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" aria-label="0,12 € / 1,00 St. Doppelherz Folsäure 800+B-Vitamine Tabletten 40 St. for €4.64 from fliegende-pillen.de" data-nt-icon-id="planti26" data-title-id="vplaurlt26" jsaction="mouseover:pla.sntiut;mouseout:pla.hntiut"></a>"""

findall = re.findall("(https?://[^\s]+)", url)

print(findall)

['http://www.fliegende-pillen.de/product/doppelherz-folsaeure-800-b-vitamine-tabletten.230477.html?p=466453&amp;noCS=1&amp;adword=google/PLA&amp;pk_campaign=google/PLA"']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, either HTML is fine or TEXT file , But the main requirement is to extract information from various DIVISIONS in the HTML file and to find not only URL but also the PRODUCT name. Since i'm new to Python, didn't find a way better than TEXT file and managed to Get the SPECIFIC set of lines, But want to get the SUBSTRING from that lines and EXTRACT the name and URL.

Comment: Also I want the PRODUCT name and it's corresponding URL's , so that's why.Any suggestions on i, Will be very helpful.

Comment: From this Line, how i can EXTRACT the URL and the name of the PRODUCT (Name usually comes after the TEXT aria-label=")                                                   
   <a href="https://www.vitaminexpress.org/de/ultra-b-complex-vitamin-b-kapseln" id="vplap27" onmousedown="return google.arwt" ontouchstart="return google.arwt(this)" class="plantl pla-unit-single-clickable-target clickable-card" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" aria-label="Ultra B Complex for €21.90 from vitaminexpress.org" data-nt-icon-id="planti27" data-title-id="vplaurlt27" jsaction="mouseover:"></a>

Comment: Hey @Linu I have edited my answer use the version at the very end